# Creating an API for an ASP.NET MVC site with rate-limiting and caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

Recently, I've been very interested in APIs, specifically in how to create them. For the purpose of this question, let's say that I have created an ASP.NET MVC site that has some data on it; I want to create an API for this site.

I have multiple questions about this:

1. **What type of API should I create?** I know that REST and oData APIs are very popular. What are the pros and cons of each, and how do I implement them? From what I understand so far, REST APIs with ASP.NET MVC would just be actions that return JSON instead of Views, and oData APIs are documented [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx).
2. **How do I handle writing?** Reading from both API types is quite simple. However, writing is more complex. With the REST approach, I understand that I can use HTTP POST, but how do I implement authentication? Also, with oData, how does writing work in the first place?
3. **How do I implement basic rate-limiting and caching?** From my past experience with APIs, these are very important things, so that the API server isn't overloaded. What's the best way to set these two things up?
4. **Can I get some sample code?** Any code that relates to C# and ASP.NET MVC would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

<sub>While this is a broad question, I think it's not *too* broad... :)</sub>

<sub>There are some similar questions to this one that are about APIs, but I haven't found any that directly address the questions I outlined here.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST service can return any media-type.  It could be a standardized one listed at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/), or it could be a custom one created by you.

OData is a protocol built on to of [AtomPub](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html).  AtomPub itself is RESTful, however, OData currently breaks a few of the REST constraints.

Authentication of a RESTful service is best done using the HTTP Authorization header.

You write to an OData service the same way you do with an AtomPub service.  Read the spec.

Personally, I would worry about writing a valuable service that delivers content efficiently before worrying about rate limiting.  You can be happy when you finally run into that problem.

For more information on caching, read [this](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: Could you point me to any sample code that concerns C# and ASP.NET MVC? Thanks anyway!